# How do I make my function game loop so that it updates the user and computer scores?

Tags: javascript

I am looping this rock paper scissors game 5 times, if user wins they get 1 if computer wins they get 1 and so on. How do i update the user and computer score? and if it ends up being a tie how do i make it so no one gets a point?

```
// Computer makes a choice
function computerPlay() {
let compchoice = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
return compchoice[Math.floor(Math.random() * compchoice.length)];
}

//Plays a single round Player vs Computer 
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
//Player
if (playerSelection === 'Rock' && computerSelection === 'Scissors') 
{
    return 'You chose ' + playerSelection + ',' + ' You win!';
} else if (playerSelection === 'Paper' && computerSelection === 
'Rock') {
    return 'You chose ' + playerSelection + ',' + ' You win!';
} else if (playerSelection === 'Scissors' && computerSelection === 
'Paper') {
    return 'You chose ' + playerSelection + ',' + ' You win!';
} 
// Computer
else if (computerSelection === 'Rock' && playerSelection === 
'Scissors') {
    return 'Computer chose ' + computerSelection + ',' + 'Computer 
wins!';
} else if (computerSelection === 'Paper' && playerSelection === 
'Rock') {
    return 'Computer chose ' + computerSelection + ',' + 'Computer 
wins!';
} else if (computerSelection === 'Scissors' && playerSelection === 
'Paper') {
    return 'Computer chose ' + computerSelection + ',' + ' Computer 
wins!';
 } else if (computerSelection === playerSelection) {
    return 'Its a draw!';
 } else {
    return 'Please chose Rock, Paper, or Scissors';
 }
}
//loops game 5 times to decide a winner.
function game() {
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
let playerSelection = prompt("Rock, Paper, Scissors");
const computerSelection = computerPlay()
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection))
console.log("your score = " + userScore);
console.log("Computer's score = " + computerScore);
}
}

let userScore =0;
let computerScore =0;

console.log(game());
```

Comment: increment your variables inside of the if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve. You just need to keep track of the scores while your loop (i.e: `game`) iterates. I modified `playRound` to return an array - the first element is signifies whether the player beat the computer in the round & the second is the message that you were originally `console.log`ing in the function:

```js
// Computer makes a choice
function computerPlay() {
  let compchoice = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
  return compchoice[Math.floor(Math.random() * compchoice.length)];
}

//Plays a single round Player vs Computer 
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  let playerWinsRound = false;
  let text;

  //Player
  if (playerSelection === 'Rock' && computerSelection === 'Scissors') {
    playerWinsRound = true;
    text = 'You chose ' + playerSelection + ',' + ' You win!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'Paper' && computerSelection ===
    'Rock') {
    playerWinsRound = true;
    text = 'You chose ' + playerSelection + ',' + ' You win!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'Scissors' && computerSelection ===
    'Paper') {
    playerWinsRound = true;
    text = 'You chose ' + playerSelection + ',' + ' You win!';
  }
  // Computer
  else if (computerSelection === 'Rock' && playerSelection ===
    'Scissors') {
    text = 'Computer chose ' + computerSelection + ', Computer wins!';
  } else if (computerSelection === 'Paper' && playerSelection ===
    'Rock') {
    text = 'Computer chose ' + computerSelection + ', Computer wins!';
  } else if (computerSelection === 'Scissors' && playerSelection ===
    'Paper') {
    text = 'Computer chose ' + computerSelection + ', Computer wins!';
  } else if (computerSelection === playerSelection) {
    playerWinsRound = null;
    text = 'Its a draw!';
  } else {
    text = 'Please chose Rock, Paper, or Scissors';
  }

  return [playerWinsRound, text];
}

//loops game 5 times to decide a winner.
function game() {
  //Score is part of the game - so move the score vars inside the game function
  let userScore = 0;
  let computerScore = 0;

  //Update the scores on each iteration of the loop (i.e.: each round)
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const playerSelection = prompt("Rock, Paper, Scissors");
    const computerSelection = computerPlay();
    const [playerWinsRound, text] = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)

    if (playerWinsRound) {
      userScore += 1;
    } else {
      if (playerWinsRound === false) {
        computerScore += 1;
      }
    }

    console.log(text);
    console.log(`Your score =  ${userScore}`);
    console.log(`Computer score = ${computerScore}`);
  }
}

game();
```